# subsection font size in table of content, beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, fontsize

Is there any possibility to change the font size of the subsections, shown in the table of content? Using the beamer class?

Answer (score 18):

This heading is controlled by `subsection in toc` and the font may be set by the `\setbeamerfont` command.

```
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\small}
```

will specify that the font size should be small.  You can specify a font family with e.g. `family=\sffamily` or a shape with `shape =\itshape`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\small}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First section}
\label{sec:first-section}

\subsection{A subsection}
\label{sec:subsection}

\begin{frame}
  Blank
\end{frame}

\subsection{A subsection}
\label{sec:subsection-1}

\begin{frame}
  Blank
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```